# Given N users with movies preferences, retrieve a list of movies preferred by at least K users

Tags: algorithm

Given **N** users with movies preferences, retrieve a list of movies preferred by at least **K** users.

What's the most efficient [Run-time / Memory] algorithm to find that answer?

If **N=K** it's easy, since you could:

1. Intersection = First user preferences.
2. For the rest of the users:
3. Intersection = intersect(Intersection, user_i)
4. If intersection is empty there's no point to continue.

(4) is the problematic in any other case, since even if there's no intersection, there's still 'potential'

I thought to create an hash-map to "Count" the amount of intersections per movie preference, but it sounds pretty inefficient. Especially if the movie preferences is huge.

Any ideas / hints? Thanks.

Comment: This looks like homework.

Comment: Are you looking for the smallest list of movies that is preferred by K users?

Comment: The first task (before even thinking about algorithms or implementations) is to understand the problem requirements. That includes putting reasonable constraints on the inputs, and specifying the resources available to solve the problem. So I would have started with a few questions: "What is the maximum value of N?" "How many movie preferences can a single user have?" "How many movies are there in total?" "How much memory is available?"

Comment: @user3386109 as I understand it you only have one preference, also I would assume he is looking for `O()` kind of answer. Maybe this info wasn't given in the interview.

Comment: @Yonlif You may be right, but then what does step 1 mean by the word "preferences". Note the plural. In fact, I see plurals throughout the question. Could be an English-as-a-second-language problem. But if that's the case, then the OP needs to clarify.

Comment: @user3386109 Haha can't believe I didn't notice the plural there. You are correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to optimize to run time, your approach of creating a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) is a good one. Basically, run over all data, and `map:movie->#users`. Then, a single iteration on the map gives you the list of movies liked by `k+` users.

This is `O(N+k)` time and `O(k)` memory.

Note that this approach can be efficiently distributed using [map-reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).

```
map:(user,movie)->(movie,1)
reduce:(movie,list<int>)->movie if sum(list)>k else none
```

---

If you want to do so with minimal added memory, you can use some inplace sorting algorithm of your data, by movie name. Then, iterate the data and count how many times a movie repeats itself, if it's k or more, yield it.

This is `O(NlogN)` run time, with minimal added memory.

- In both solutions, `N` stands for the input size (number of entries), which is potentially `O(n*k)`, but practically much less.